# Repeating Values inside JCOMBOBOX

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

I'm trying to update the Value inside a `JComboBox` but the problem is when I add or delete a value all of the names inside the `JComboBox` is repeated how can I fix this? I tried to put it after connection close but it didn't work

Here is my Code:

```
  private void cmbNamesPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                      

  try{

     String tmp=(String)cmbNames.getSelectedItem();    
     String sql="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Fname=?";
     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.setString(1,tmp);
     rs=pst.executeQuery();

     if(rs.next()){              
          String add1=rs.getString("ID");
          txtID.setText(add1);              
          String add2=rs.getString("Fname");
          txtFirst.setText(add2);              
          String add3=rs.getString("Lname");
          txtLast.setText(add3);              
          String add4=rs.getString("Username");
          txtUser.setText(add4);            
          String add5=rs.getString("Password");
          txtPass.setText(add5);            
          cmdUpdate.setEnabled(true);
          cmdDelete.setEnabled(true);
          cmdAdd.setEnabled(false);              
      }            
    }        
    catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);     
    }
}
```

and here is the code I used in Names():

```
     private void Names(){

      try{
        String sql="Select fname from account";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String name=rs.getString("fname");
            cmbNames.addItem(name);

        }
        rs.close();
         pst.close(); 
    }

    catch(SQLException e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
    }
    finally{
     try{
         rs.close();
         pst.close();

     }
     catch(SQLException e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: forgot about to call JDBC from internal JComboBoxes event PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible,

Answer (score 3):

Your update from the database add items from a query.  Each time you run this it is only going to keep adding items.  Clear the combo box before you run the update.

For example, add this line before you loop through your result set.

```
cmbNames.removeAllItems();
```